# Marriage Visitor Visa - Eventually Settle in UK (US Citizen)

Tags: immigration, us-citizens, marriage

I'm a US citizen intending on marrying my UK citizen fiancé. However, I'm not sure whether my situation will fall under a Marriage Visitor Visit or a Fiancé Visa. I'm still a little new to this but I want to apply for a visitor visa because at the time of marriage, I will have too many investments at home and cannot stay indefinitely in the UK. However, after some time, I would like to immigrate to the UK once everything settles down. Is that possible or is this considered "cheating the system"? I know with a Fiancé, you show intent of settlement but again, I cannot settle immediately. Can someone please help me understand which option is best? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not 'cheating the system' and indeed this is one of the purpose's of a Marriage Visa (it covers a few scenarios). Just demonstrate everything you've stated here clearly and your application *should be* relatively straightforward.